# Non-Deep copy of DOM element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, clone, deep-copy

Is it possible to create a clone/copy of a DOM element in jQuery without cloning its content? I need to split the content of a div into two separate divs with the same attributes. So for example I need to change:

```
<div class="someclass" someattr="someval">
    this is the first sentence. this is the second sentence.
</div>
```

into something like:

```
<div class="someclass" someattr="someval">
    this is the first sentence.
</div>
<div class="someclass" someattr="someval">
    this is the second sentence.
</div>
```

How exactly the content is split is rather complicated, but this is basically what I need to do. Obviously, creating a clone without content can be achieved using:

```
$(el).clone().empty();
```

But since my element can become rather large, I would like to get rid of the overhead of unnecessarily cloning the element content. Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The only other option is to not use .clone() and create the div with the attributes manually.

Comment: does your `div.someclass` has only text or there also some other elements present in it?

Comment: The problem is that the element I want to clone is arbitrary - it can have arbitrary attributes and arbitrary, even nested content, so doing it manually is not really an option. I will go for the `clone().empty()` approach for now and see how it performs.

Answer (score 7):

Just go around jQuery for this operation, as long as you don't need to keep (non-attribute-based) event listeners or other data.

```
var $clone = $(el.cloneNode(false));
```